# Given only the slope, find the shortest distance from a line to a point on the x-axis

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, graphing-functions, slope

[image]

I have the following amusing question.

Suppose that the red dot is the point $x = -1$

The blue line is the line crossing the origin with slope $-1/k, k > 0$

I wish to find the length of the purple line, which is the shortest distance from the blue line to the red dot.

Can this be done or do I need additional information?

Comment: Are the x- and y-intercepts of the line both zero, as shown in the diagram, or can they have other values?

Comment: Both zero. The line is exactly $y = -(1/k) x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the perpendicular distance formula: $d = \frac{ax_1 + by_1 + c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$ with $x_1 = -1, y_1 = 0$ (the coordinates of the given point) and $a = 1, b = k, c = 0$ (by writing the equation of the line in general form). This gives $d = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+k^2}}$.

Note that this even works for $k < 0$ (but obviously not for $k = 0$).

Comment: Thank you. Do you have a proof?

Comment: Of the formula?

Comment: Yes, I don't immediately see how this is true, even though I have an intuitive feeling it is

Comment: https://www.intmath.com/plane-analytic-geometry/perpendicular-distance-point-line.php

Comment: My goodness. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Guide:

- Let the acute angle between the blue line and the negative $x$-axis be $\theta$. Since the slope is $-\frac1k$. Can you compute $\tan \theta$?
- The length of the purple line is $\sin \theta$.

$$\tan \theta = \frac{\sin\theta}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta}}$$

Comment: The last formula you wrote doesn't make sense since $\sin \theta > 0$ (you said that it is a length) so the RHS is positive, but $\tan \theta$ is clearly negative in this case since it is equal to the gradient of the line.

Comment: $\theta$ is an acute angle. its tangent is positive.

Comment: You should specify that $\theta$ is the angle between the blue line and the negative $x-$axis.

Comment: sure, thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You have a line
$$\bbox{ y(x) = - \frac{x}{k} }$$
We'll assume $0 \ne k \in \mathbb{R}$; i.e. $k$ may be any nonzero real.

The distance squared from point $(-1, 0)$ to $(x, y(x))$ is $(x-1)^2 + (y(x))^2$. As a function of $x$,
$$\bbox{ L_2(x) = (x - 1)^2 + \bigr( y(x) \bigr)^2 = \frac{k^2 + 1}{k^2} x^2 + 2 x + 1 }$$
Since this is continuous and differentiable, it reaches an extrema when its derivative,
$$\bbox{ \frac{d L_2(x)}{d x} = \frac{2 k^2 + 2}{k^2} x + 2 }$$
is zero:
$$\bbox{ \frac{2 k^2 + 2}{k^2} x + 2 = 0 } \quad \iff \quad \bbox{ x = - \frac{k^2}{k^2 + 1} }$$
Substituting that back to the distance squared, and taking a square root, we find that the minimum distance is
$$\bbox{ L_{min} = \sqrt{L_2\left(-\frac{k^2}{k^2 + 1}\right)} }$$
where the expression in the square root is $L_2(x)$ when $x = -k^2 / (k^2 + 1)$.

That simplifies to
$$\bbox{ L_{min} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{k^2 + 1}} }$$

We can make this cover all $k \in \mathbb{R}$, by noting that when $k = 0$, is passes via the point $(-1, 0)$, so then the distance is zero:
$$\bbox[#fffff7]{
\text{Minimum distance} = \begin{cases}
0, & k = 0 \\
\displaystyle \frac{1}{\sqrt{k^2 + 1}}, & k \ne 0
\end{cases} }$$